# Can't install libraries on Python via Pycharm/VSCode

Tags: installation, python, libraries

I'm having an issue when trying to install any python library via Terminal with 'pip install' command.

I have already tried to install seaborn and got the same 'failed with exit status 2' error, below I'll paste what Pycharm's Terminal shows me with the error

```
(venv) E:\01_Samuel\PyCharm>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/d1/7b12cd79c791348cb0c78ce6e7d16bd72992f13c9f1e8e43d2725a6d8adf/matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in e:\01_samuel\pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (40.8.0)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    Complete output from command E:\01_Samuel\PyCharm\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\csamu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3d3ow7iz\\matplotlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().rep
lace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\csamu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rrx9xnhm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers E:\01_Samuel\PyCharm\venv\include\site\python3
.8\matplotlib:
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
          python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC
                      v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]]
        platform: yes [win32]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
             agg: yes [installing]
           tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
            dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying lib\pylab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\afm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\artist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\axis.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backend_bases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backend_managers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\forward_large.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-bright.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-pastel.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\cmmi10.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-dark.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\zoom_to_rect.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\external
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\external\jquery
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\external\jquery\jquery.js -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\external\jquery
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmex10.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvl8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\single_figure.html -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\psyr.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-muted.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\qt4_editor_options.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\move.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.min.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\zoom_to_rect_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizFourSymBol.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\move_large.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXNonUniBolIta.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizThreeSymBol.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images\ui-icons_444444_256x240.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pbkli8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\putri8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmtt10.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\s1045.ima.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\ptmb8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.theme.min.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\forward_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\back.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery\js
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery\js\jquery.js -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery\js
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\back_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\zoom_to_rect.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\subplots.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery\js\jquery.min.js -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery\js
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\LICENSE_DEJAVU -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\move.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\css\fbm.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\css
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSerif.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\ZapfDingbats.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\matplotlib.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\nbagg_uat.ipynb -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pncr8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pbkd8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\eeg.dat -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\subplots.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvb8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pncbi8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Courier.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Helvetica-Oblique.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSansDisplay.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvr8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-darkgrid.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\help.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvro8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\grace_hopper.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\zoom_to_rect.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\LICENSE.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\goog.npz -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\move_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXNonUni.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Symbol.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\dark_background.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\home.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXNonUniBol.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\qt4_editor_options.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\fast.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\js\mpl.js -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\js
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\ptmri8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\topobathy.npz -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\ct.raw.gz -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-talk.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\putb8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizTwoSymReg.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\all_figures.html -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXGeneralBolIta.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSans.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.structure.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Helvetica-Bold.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.structure.min.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSerifDisplay.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvro8an.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-poster.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pplb8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\percent_bachelors_degrees_women_usa.csv -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXGeneral.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\fivethirtyeight.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\embedding_in_wx3.xrc -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\back.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\putbi8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\help.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\subplots_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\back.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvbo8an.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmmi10.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pncri8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Courier-Oblique.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\grayscale.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.theme.css -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\cmex10.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXGeneralItalic.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave_large.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\home_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images\ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmsy10.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Helvetica-BoldOblique.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\move.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\hand.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images\ui-icons_555555_256x240.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\data_x_x2_x3.csv -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\zoom_to_rect.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\ada.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\phvbo8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizFiveSymReg.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-ticks.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\hand.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXGeneralBol.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\cmtt10.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\ptmr8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\cmr10.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pcrro8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\qt4_editor_options_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\back_large.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\subplots_large.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pagko8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSansMono.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmr10.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\js\mpl_tornado.js -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\js
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-deep.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Courier-BoldOblique.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images\ui-icons_777777_256x240.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizThreeSymReg.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\Minduka_Present_Blue_Pack.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\logo2.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\help.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-white.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data\None_vs_nearest-pdf.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts\Helvetica.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\pdfcorefonts
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\filesave.pdf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images\ui-icons_cc0000_256x240.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-dark-palette.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\seaborn-whitegrid.mplstyle -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmss10.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm\pbkl8a.afm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\afm
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizOneSymBol.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXSizTwoSymBol.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\forward.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\help_large.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\forward.svg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\help_large.ppm -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib\_version.py to '3.1.1'
    running build_ext
    building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1
_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iextern/agg24-svn/include -IE:\01_Samuel\PyCharm\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IE:\01_Samuel\PyCharm\venv\include -IC:\Users\csamu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\csamu\AppData\Local\Pr
ograms\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\s
hared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/checkdep_freetype2.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8
\Release\src/checkdep_freetype2.obj
    checkdep_freetype2.c
    src/checkdep_freetype2.c(1): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "E:\01_Samuel\PyCharm\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\csamu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3d3ow7iz\\matplotlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.clo
se();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\csamu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rrx9xnhm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers E:\01_Samuel\PyCharm\venv\include\site\python3.8\matplotlib" failed wi
th error code 1 in C:\Users\csamu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3d3ow7iz\matplotlib\
```

I have this error when trying to install libraries via pip in the VSCODE too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Matplotlib on Windows 10 machines](https://superuser.com/questions/1498353/installing-matplotlib-on-windows-10-machines)

Answer (score 0):

[Seaborn](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/) uses Matplotlib under the hood:

> Seaborn is a library for making statistical graphics in Python. It is built on top of matplotlib and closely integrated with pandas data structures.

So it isn't much of a surprise that both are failing.

Importantly, [Matplotlib on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files) (where `pip` draws packages from) doesn't have any `.whl` files for Python 3.8 yet (as of this writing). So Python is trying to build Matplotlib from scratch and is failing.

If you are okay with using "unofficial" builds of Matplotlib for Python 3.8 [you can download them here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors.