# Installing Matplotlib on Windows 10 machines

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to install Matplotlib on my Windows 10 64-bit computer using Python's `pip` installer. Any advice would be appreciated. When I try I get the following extensive error return that I do not understand:

```
C:\Users\Todd Huffman>python -m pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/d1/7b12cd79c791348cb0c78ce6e7d16bd72992f13c9f1e8e43d2725a6d8adf/matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\python38\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (41.2.0)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Todd Huffman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_sa1y_nr\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Todd Huffman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_sa1y_nr\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Todd Huffman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-50m5un7r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Todd Huffman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_sa1y_nr\matplotlib\
    Complete output (505 lines):
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
          python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC
                      v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
             agg: yes [installing]
           tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
            dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying lib\pylab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\afm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\animation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\artist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backend_bases.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backend_managers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\backend_tools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\bezier.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\blocking_input.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\category.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\cm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\collections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\colorbar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\colors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\container.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\contour.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\dates.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\dviread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\figure.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\font_manager.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\gridspec.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\hatch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\legend.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\legend_handler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\lines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\markers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mathtext.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\mlab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\offsetbox.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\patches.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\path.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\patheffects.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\pylab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\pyplot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\quiver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\rcsetup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\sankey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\scale.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\spines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\stackplot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\streamplot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\texmanager.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\text.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\textpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\ticker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\tight_bbox.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\tight_layout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\transforms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\type1font.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\units.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\widgets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_animation_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_cm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_cm_listed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_color_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_constrained_layout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_layoutbox.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_mathtext_data.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_pylab_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\axes
    copying lib\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\axes
    copying lib\matplotlib\axes\_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\axes
    copying lib\matplotlib\axes\_secondary_axes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\axes
    copying lib\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\axes
    copying lib\matplotlib\axes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\axes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_cairo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3agg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3cairo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_macosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_mixed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_nbagg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_pgf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_ps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4cairo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5cairo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_svg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkcairo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_webagg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_webagg_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_wxagg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\backend_wxcairo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\windowing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\wx_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\_backend_pdf_ps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\cbook
    copying lib\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\cbook
    copying lib\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\cbook
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\compat
    copying lib\matplotlib\compat\subprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\compat
    copying lib\matplotlib\compat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\compat
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\projections
    copying lib\matplotlib\projections\geo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\projections
    copying lib\matplotlib\projections\polar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\projections
    copying lib\matplotlib\projections\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\projections
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\sphinxext
    copying lib\matplotlib\sphinxext\mathmpl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\sphinxext
    copying lib\matplotlib\sphinxext\plot_directive.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\sphinxext
    copying lib\matplotlib\sphinxext\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\sphinxext
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\style
    copying lib\matplotlib\style\core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\style
    copying lib\matplotlib\style\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\style
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\compare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\decorators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\determinism.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\disable_internet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\triangulation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\tricontour.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\trifinder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\triinterpolate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\tripcolor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\triplot.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\trirefine.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\tritools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    copying lib\matplotlib\tri\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\tri
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formsubplottool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\_formlayout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\Duration.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\Epoch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\EpochConverter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\StrConverter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\UnitDbl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\UnitDblConverter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\UnitDblFormatter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    copying lib\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\testing\jpl_units
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\anchored_artists.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\angle_helper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axes_divider.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axes_grid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axes_rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axes_size.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axislines.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axisline_style.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\axis_artist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\clip_path.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\colorbar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\floating_axes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\grid_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\grid_helper_curvelinear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\inset_locator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\parasite_axes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\anchored_artists.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\axes_divider.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\axes_grid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\axes_rgb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\axes_size.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\colorbar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\inset_locator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\mpl_axes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\parasite_axes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axisartist
    copying lib\mpl_toolkits\axisartist\angle_helper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\mpl_toolkits\axisartist

<many more 'copying' entries ensue and we pick it up later>

    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\STIXGeneral.ttf -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf
    UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\_version.py
    set build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\matplotlib\_version.py to '3.1.1'
    running build_ext
    building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019NEW\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iextern/agg24-svn/include -ID:\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -ID:\Python38\include -ID:\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019NEW\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019NEW\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/checkdep_freetype2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/checkdep_freetype2.obj
    checkdep_freetype2.c
    src/checkdep_freetype2.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019NEW\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Todd Huffman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_sa1y_nr\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Todd Huffman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_sa1y_nr\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Todd Huffman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-50m5un7r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: We see four outputs. Which one of it is related to your command? Can you access the `ft2build.h` File?

Comment: ALL of these were related to my command. And this wasn't all of it, I had to skip out some of the "copying ..." lines in order to get the output to fit in here. 
I tried to keep everything that looked like it might contain an error.

Comment: The file ft2build.h does not seem to exist on any of my disks.

Comment: It looks like I need to get the freetype binaries for Windows from here? https://github.com/ubawurinna/freetype-windows-binaries/tree/master/win64 
but where would one put those binaries?

Comment: Just tried putting the freetype.dll and freetype.lib files and then setting LIB, INCLUDE, and PATH environment variables to point to their locations...no luck.

Comment: It is difficult to debug like this, using an InterNet Relay Chat kind of conversation. What you need is an Expert in the _Python_ Dynamic Interpreted Programming Language. Try to approach @Anaksunaman's solution and see where it is leading.

Answer (score 2):

[Matplotlib on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files) (where `pip` draws packages from) doesn't have any .`whl` files for Python 3.8 yet (as of this writing). So Python is (as you seem to be aware) trying to build from scratch and is failing. For what it's worth, I have personally run into similar issues with Python 3.8/Matplotlib.

If you want a quick solution, you should look at [this page run by Christoph Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). In short, it contains an extremely wide selection of "unofficial" Windows builds of various Python packages, include Matplotlib 3.1.1 for Python 3.8 in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors (`matplotlib‑3.1.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl` and `matplotlib‑3.1.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` respectively).

Simply download the appropriate `.whl` for your version of Python and use e.g. `python -m pip install nameof.whl` to install the wheel. You can use `python -v` if you aren't aware of whether your version of Python is 32-bit or 64-bit.

---

*As a side note, independent of Python 3.8, I ran into an issue where Matplotlib 3.1.1 would crash Python every time I went to run a Matplotlib script. The offending package was actually the PyPI build of `numpy`, specifically the DLL for OpenBLAS. I resolved this issue by uninstalling the PyPI version of `numpy` and replacing it with a build of `numpy+mkl` from the page already cited. Just a bit of extra information if you run into any similar issues.*

---

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I am guessing though that Matplotlib on PyPI will want to develop a wheel for Python 3.8 very soon? If that timescale is short enough I might be better off waiting do you think?

Comment: Based on a post this [Matplotlib GitHub Issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15041) it looks like Python 3.8 wheels are scheduled to be released with Matplotlib 3.2.0 (which apparently just got a pre-release RC1 version 3 weeks ago). Based on the [official GitHub releases](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/releases), it looks like there was about a month between the last RC1 for 3.1.0 and it's official release. So it's possible there might be official wheels in the next couple of weeks, give or take. But that is assuming there is no RC2 (as there was with 3.1.0).

Comment: It's a bit hard to recommend one way or the other (since I am unsure what your intending to use this for). Personally, I haven't encountered any issues with Matplotlib itself on 3.8 (other than what's already been discussed). The builds referenced *seem* stable. If you want to get a jump, I would probably say they are fine. But there is no harm in waiting either, I suppose. I prefer official builds myself. That said, you can always simply `python -m pip uninstall matplotlib` if you ever want to remove the suggested versions. Python is typically good about keeping module dependencies intact.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and thanks Christoph Gohlke, whoever you may be, for providing this immensely valuable resource.