# Error occurs when I try to install sklearn by pip

Tags: python3, pip

**Version info:**

- python: 3.8
- scipy: 1.3.2
- numpy: 1.17.4

**Details:** It works well when I install other libs;
however, it throws the below error message when I install sklearn by pip or pip3.

**Error message:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using Python 3.8, there are quite a few modules that do not have official `.whl` files for Python 3.8 available on PyPI (where `pip` downloads modules from). [scikit-learn is currently one of those modules](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#files). That said, scikit-learn has unofficial Python 3.8 modules available [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). SciPy and Numpy+MKL are also available from that link (I am not sure how `sklearn` might fit into everything in this case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Matplotlib on Windows 10 machines](https://superuser.com/questions/1498353/installing-matplotlib-on-windows-10-machines)

Comment: (1) Please post the screen output as text.   (2) It says “Check the logs” — did you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.@Anaksunaman